# pymongo error operation failure

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, pymongo

I'm currently using celery with django, i have 
pymongo ver 1.11
mongodb ver 1.8

I'm getting following error, i'm not able to figure out what is the error.

```
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,544: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 293, in command
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,560: WARNING/MainProcess] msg, allowable_errors)
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,560: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 126, in _check_command_response
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] raise OperationFailure(msg % response["errmsg"])
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] pymongo.errors
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] .
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] OperationFailure
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2011-09-23 02:06:59,561: WARNING/MainProcess] command SON([('findandmodify', 'messages'), ('query', {'queue': 'celery'}), ('remove', True)]) failed: exception: nextSafe(): { $err: "using a newer index version: { v: 1, key: { queue: 1 }, ns: "kombu_def...", code: 13658 }
```

Comment: Did you upgrade to MongoDB 2.0 (or 1.9.x) and then back down to 1.8 or earlier? If you rolled back to 1.8.3, you can use the `reindex` command on your collection; if you rolled back to 1.8.2 or earlier, you should drop and recreate indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its to do with MongoDB indexes are using version 1 which relates to mongodb >= 2.0

see: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Index+Versions

Comment: Thanks Ross for the link, although the steps didn't helped much, i had drop the collection only and then it started working.